# Is it possible to modify default Microsoft Outlook Schedule Appointment view?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar, appointments

This is an image of an MS Outlook Apointment viewed in the Schedule view.  The text displayed is from Subject, Location, Meeting Organiser and 1st line of message body.

Is it possible to remove some of these fields from being displayed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is no built-in option in Outlook to customize the Appointment schedule view.

But if you only need to remove the "message body" part ("THIS IS TEST" in your image above), you can change the view from "Preview" to "Calendar":

[image]